# Catkin_make does not see the package

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin_make does not see the package

```
root@ubn:~/catkin_ws# rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.014544 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.013431   /opt/ros/kinetic/share
0.000467   /home/amburkoff/catkin_ws/src
0.000206 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev
0.000109 * /home/amburkoff/catkin_ws/src/joy_twist <------------------------
0.000040 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/haarcascades
0.000029 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc
0.000018 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/lbpcascades
0.000012 * /home/amburkoff/catkin_ws/src/joy_twist/launch
0.000011 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/gscam
0.000010 * /home/amburkoff/catkin_ws/src/joy_twist/src
0.000006 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc/liborocos-kdl
root@ubn:~/catkin_ws# rospack find joy_twist
[rospack] Error: package 'joy_twist' not found <------------------------
root@ubn:~/catkin_ws# rospack find gscam
/home/amburkoff/catkin_ws/src/gscam
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295786/catkin_make-does-not-see-the-package/) by [amburkoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/18441/amburkoff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2018-06-29**:
Hi, could you please provide more details about your problem? Where did you get this package from? Does this package has a CMakeLists.txt and a package.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output from `rospack profile` gives you your answer: `home/amburkoff/catkin_ws/src/joy_twist` doesn't contain a [Manifest](http://wiki.ros.org/Manifest), which every ROS package needs to have.  You might want to take a look at this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) to see how packages are normally created in ROS, or maybe use an example from another package.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2